# Задать номер месяца по его названию. C#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Имеется ComboBox, который хранит месяца года в текстовом формате. Как можно записать номер месяца в DataTime?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Там где происходит  добавление месяцев  в список, нужный мне номер месяца сохранить сразу не могу, так как нужен выбор пользователя.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
{
   cmbMonth.Items.Add(now.ToString("MMMM"));
   now = now.AddMonths(1);
   cmbMonth.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM");
}
```

Нужно из `cmbMonth.Text` получить название месяца, что бы записать полноценную дату выбранную пользователем. Но так-как месяца хранятся в виде текста, возникли проблемы. Как можно решить? (Писать цикл с месяцами и их номерами не вариант, так как текст месяца в ComboBox зависит от языка системы)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для перевода из `String` в `DataTime` есть пара хороших методов `Parse` и `ParseExact`. Вот второй и подойдет для данной задачи!

Суть следующая - Вы ему даете 3 аргумента:

1. `string`, где есть значения связанные со временем (будь то время, дата, месяц или еще что).
2. Некая маска, по которой метод `ParseExact` поймет, что находится в пункте 1.
3. Культура пользователя или указанная заранее.

Напишу пример к вашей задаче:

```
var m = "Декабрь";
DateTime dd = DateTime.ParseExact(m, "MMMM", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
Console.WriteLine(dd);
```

Как видим я задал 3 параметра - месяц (декабрь), маска (полный формат месяца) и культура (текущая культура пользователя).

Результатом программа выдаст:

```
01.12.2018 0:00:00
```

Надеюсь это решит вашу проблему. Удачи!

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое! Чётко, понятно и то, что нужно было. Огромное спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2):

Небольшой пример работы с комбобоксом, где в качестве элемента будет не строка, а наш класс.

```
class MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm()
    {
        var cb = new ComboBox();
        var currMonth = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-DateTime.Now.Day + 1);

        for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            var dt = currMonth.AddMonths(i);
            cb.Items.Add(new MonthItem { Id = dt.Month, Text = dt.ToString("MMMM") });
        }

        cb.DisplayMember = "Text";

        cb.SelectedIndexChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            var m = (cb.SelectedItem as MonthItem);
            if (m != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Selected {m.Text} with ID = {m.Id}");
            }

        };

        this.Controls.Add(cb);
    }

    private class MonthItem
    {
        public int Id { get; set;}
        public string Text { get; set;}
    }
}
```

И как результат

[image]
[image]

Comment: Спасибо Вам за ответ. Несомненно в будущем может пригодиться при работе с ComboBox.

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, лучше хранить в комбобоксе непосредственно значения `DateTime`. При этом настроить формат комбобокса для отображения в желаемом виде.

Значение `cmbKuu.Text` достаточно установить один раз, вынеся его из цикла. Кроме того, следует предусмотреть тот почти невероятный случай, когда между выполнением двух операторов произойдёт смена месяца на компьютере, в результате чего в `cmbKuu` может оказаться следующий месяц. Поэтому не вызываем `DateTime.Now` дважды.

```
var now = DateTime.Now;

cmbMonth.FormattingEnabled = true;
cmbMonth.FormatString = "MMMM";

cmbKuu.Text = now.ToString("MMMM");

for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
{
    cmbMonth.Items.Add(now);
    now = now.AddMonths(1);
}
```

Теперь в обработчике события можно получить выбранное значение `DateTime` и использовать его свойства.

```
private void CmbMonth_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dateTime = (DateTime)cmbMonth.SelectedItem;

    // используем dateTime.Month
}
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам за ответ. Буду иметь в виду!